# How to gracefully handle "SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE ..." in node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg, node-postgres

I am using a `Pool` to resolve `PoolClient` objects out of. I know why the error is occuring, I just haven't provided a password, but irrespective I would like to handle the authentication error gracefully.

I tried:

- Wrapping `pool.connect()` in try-catch
- Adding `on('error')` to both `Pool` and `PoolClient` objects.

Comment: What is the graceful way of saying you can't do anything useful until someone fixes the password?  And what happened when you tried those things you tried?

Comment: This is a well-known issue in the lib itself, and unfortunately it was not resolved ever- https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue in the lib itself, and unfortunately it was not resolved ever- [github issue reference](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/746)

If you are using this in express, my suggestion will be to have a global error handler, which catches all unhandled exceptions, which should capture the bubbled up error. Something like this-

```js
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  return res.status(500).send({err});
});
```